# Oracle Apex: APEX version of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a table that holds values of columns in APEX similar to `all_tab_columns`?

`all_tab_columns` shows column headers like they are in a database, but on APEX, a lot of these headers are formatted to be a bit more user-friendly in interactive reports.  I wanted to find if there was a table like this that showed the following mappings:

Database                   --> APEX

Column Name: dept_no --> Department Number

My hunch is that this data is stored somewhere in a many-to-many mapping where on Interactive Report for a given page, `department_no` may be mapped to the string "Department Number" or, if filtered, this could be mapped to "Accounting Department Number" for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything defined in APEX is held in a table somewhere.  For convenience, APEX also exposes these through various views: the view you want for Interactive Report columns is APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_COL and the columns of interest are:

- APPLICATION_ID
- PAGE_ID
- COLUMN_ALIAS
- REPORT_LABEL

You can find these views via the APEX Builder tool under Workspace Utilities -> Application Express Views.  You can also find them via SQL tools - they belong to a schema called `APEX_nnnnnn` where `nnnnnn` represents the version of APEX you are using e.g. `APEX_050100`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to locate these dictionary views is to use a query like this

`select * from apex_dictionary
where apex_view_name like '%IR%'
and column_id = 0;`

I use these views *all* the time

http://davidsgale.com/the-apex-data-dictionary/